# AWS API Gateway websocket send message to connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to send a message back from AWS API gateway websocket which has been routed to my lambda.

I am currently able to retrieve the connectionID but I seem to have some trouble sending a message back to the connection using python or postman.

Following the [docs](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-how-to-call-websocket-api-connections.html), I have been sending post requests to the following:

```
https://<API_ID>.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/<STAGE>/@connections/<connectionID>
```

Can anyone verify if I am doing this correctly? I seem to be getting the following response

```
{
    "message": "Missing Authentication Token"
}
```

Is there supposed to be an Auth Token to be parsed to the websocket api?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved it, apparently I needed to include my AWS authorisation in Postman. Head to `Authorization` and select `AWS Signature`